# Listview Item Display Error wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

ListViewItem.ListViewItem()
Initializes a new instance of the ?System.windows.controls.listViewItem class.
Error:
System.Window.Controls.ListViewItem does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Code:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace AlisLogin.View
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for ControlPanel.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ControlPanel : Window
    {
        public ControlPanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SilverLightInstalled();
        }

        private void SilverLightInstalled()
        {

        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string uninstallKey = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";
            using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(uninstallKey))
            {
            foreach (string skName in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
            {
                using (RegistryKey sk = rk.OpenSubKey(skName))
                {
                    try
                    {

                        var displayName = sk.GetValue("DisplayName");
                        var size = sk.GetValue("EstimatedSize");

                        ListViewItem item;
                        if (displayName != null)
                        {
                            if (size != null)
                                item = new ListViewItem(new string[] {displayName.ToString(), size.ToString()});

                            else
                                item = new ListViewItem(new string[] { displayName.ToString() });
                                lvlUser.Items.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    { }
                }
            }

        }  
    }
}
```

xaml:

```
<Grid>
        <Button Content="Get All Programs" Margin="0 5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="111" Click="Button_Click_1"/>
        <ListView Name="lvlUser" Margin="0 30 0 0">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="EstimatedTime"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="DisplayVersion"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="InstallDate"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Publisher"/>                    
                    <GridViewColumn Header="InstalledOn"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
```

Comment: If read your exception carefully and you take look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listviewitem.listviewitem(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this -

```
 item = new ListViewItem();
 item.Content = new string[] {displayName.ToString(), size.ToString()};

 lvlUser.Items.Add(item);
```

More information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listviewitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)